# Functions that vanish weakly to $\infty$ and a uniqueness problem

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, fractional-calculus

I am reading the article "User’s guide to the fractional Laplacian and the method of semigroups" by P.R. Stinga, there is a [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.05159.pdf). At page 17, in theorem 7, the author state that, for a given $u\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, there is a unique solution $U=U(x,y)\colon\mathbb{R}^n\times[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ to:
$$ \Delta U+\frac{a}{y}U_y+U_{yy}=0\quad\text{in }\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,\infty),$$
$$ U(x,0)=u(x),\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n,$$
that vanish weakly to $+\infty$. My questions are

1. what does it mean that $U$ vanish weakly to $\infty$?
2. How i can prove that if there exists a solution that vanish weakly it is unique?

I don't know how to proceed. Nor do I know very little about this subject. Any help is appreciated.